# How to divide page both horizontal and vertical with Bootstrap

Tags: css

id like to divide my homepage in 3 parts. Basically split horizontally 30%,70% and then split the second row in two 50%,50% columns
only way i know is with frameset but since i need to use bootstrap.

Comment: use bootstrap grid. read more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: honestly? Did you even tried to open the documentation? Stuff like grid is well present there. Also which version of Bootstrap are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has columns, these columns divide the page into 12 sections. So if you wanted to have a row divided in 50% 50% you can look at below how to do it.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row .col-xs-6{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7g7Lh2L2/3/

so if you want to add different widths then change the column number after xs, I recommend you look at grids for bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">One</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">Three</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Four</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```